# Getting pages defined by taxonomy to display in a view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, display-suite, entities

I have a page view that displays video thumbnails in a grid layout (three columns.) Above each thumbnail is the title of the video and below it is the category. The category is defined by taxonomy and selected by the user when he uploads his video.

The overall view (all videos regardless of their category - ex: /videos/all) displays nicely in a page view (no taxonomy term involved here.)

The display problem arises when a user selects a category. Although the items belonging to that category are properly filtered, I cannot get a view (ex: videos/movies) to display them in the same manner as the overall view (three columns.) I get instead the node teaser layout (thumbnails in one column with a "read more" link below each. A page view with the same path as the corresponding taxonomy term (ex: videos/movies) does not take control of the display.

How can I solve this and have all category views display like the videos/all page? Display Suite does not "see" the videos/movies page created by taxonomy.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7,  you can use [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context) module.

- Context : It allows you to easily organize your site into manageable sections .
- Create a **new** context using the **path - videos/%category** and arrange the items like **Overall View**.

Note : [Context](http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-context-module#)